# How to sort a matrix in Julia

Tags: r, julia

I am working with a matrix that looks like this in Julia:

```
1-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,2},1},1}:
Array{Int64,2}[[14 32; 32 77]]
```

I want to sort the matrix in decreasing order just as I did in R with an output that looks like this:

```
[1] 77 32 32 14
```

I tried using this function in Julia:

```
[sort(z, rev=true)]
```

but I get the same matrix I started with, unsorted. Is it possible to sort a matrix in Julia so that it has a 1D output like in R?

Comment: Your object is of type `Array{Array{Array{Int64,2},1},1}`. Hence it is not a matrix but a vector of a vector of matrices. This seems strange to me and you should probably overthink this data format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same spirit:

```
m=[[14 32; 32 77]]
sort(collect(Iterators.flatten(m)), rev=true)
```

Output:

```
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 77
 32
 32
 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
m = [[14 32; 32 77]]
sort(hcat(m...)[:], rev=true)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Are there any arguments that go in the [:] part? Sorry, I am fairly new to Julia.

Comment: It effectively does the same as `Iterators.flatten`; turns a 2D matrix into a 1D vector